# Solving a system of ODEs with changing parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, vector-fields

I want to plot (Preferably in Desmos or something like that) a system of ODEs with changing parameters $a,b,h>0$.
$$
\begin{split}
x' &= x(1-ax-y)\\
y' &= y(b-x-y)+h
\end{split}
$$
How do I got about doing this?

Comment: I can clearly use the nullclines of the system to create a rough sketch of how it looks but my parameters change the slope of the nullclines.

Comment: Do you mean you want to plot the numerical solutions to the ODE system?  You can do this with wxMaxima (a free equivalent of Mathematica) or with Python: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928750/numerical-ode-solving-in-python]

Comment: The best way to do this is via Mathematica's Manipulate and NSolve functions.